# Get the path after "n" directory in the whole path

Tags: bash, shell, path, terminal, directory

I want to cut this path to get the remaining path after an "n"th directory

ORIGINAL PATH

```
/home/user/path/to/something/useful
```

In bash if I pass in 2, it should give me

```
/path/to/something/useful
```

If I use 3, it gives me

```
/to/something/useful
```

I need this using bash. I know pwd gives me the current director and `cut -d/ -f4 <<<"$PWD"` gives me the third directory
But not sure how to get the remaining path after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `-` to the `-f4` to get the fourth field and everything after.

```
cut -d/ -f4- <<< "$PWD"
```